# Using the JExcel API, how do I enter a cell value of unknown data type without a hidden apostrophe being added?

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I'm using the JExcel API to create an XLS file.  I can't figure out how to populate a new cell without any specific cell formatting.  I would like the formatting to be automatically applied, as it does in Excel when you type a value in a cell and it auto-detects what it thinks you're trying to enter.

I wrote something similar to this:

```
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;

WritableWorkbook w = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(xlsPath));
WritableSheet sheet = w.createSheet("Sheet1", 0);
sheet.addCell(new Label(colNum, rowNum, "99"));
```

Because I used a 'Label', the value entered in the cell is '99 -- notice the apostrophe in the value, forcing it to be evaluated as a text value.  Other potential classes to use are Blank, Boolean, DateTime, Formula, Label, and Number.  The problem is that I don't know what type the cell value will be when I'm setting it.

How can I enter my values in the field without knowing the data type, and without the JExcel API prefixing my values with apostrophes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those apostrophes only show up when I open the new workbook using OpenOffice.  If I open it using Excel, then the apostrophes don't automatically get added.  So in this case, using the Label class seems to be working OK.  I'll call this an OpenOffice oddity.